# OSX app - adding file without damaging certificate

Tags: macos, signing

I want to add a file to a signed mac app without damaging its signature. How do I do that?

Basically, I have a signed mac app that can be downloaded from my website. I want to add a few parameters(in a new file say user_data.txt) to my app which is relevant to the users(like his/her email address) when it is downloaded each time. How do I do that without damaging the signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I included a file, say user_data.txt, in the app before codesign. While doing codesign, I used --resource-rules to ignore signing of that particular file. This is an one time task
2. Each time when a user attempts to download this file, I modify the user_data.txt and write the modified app file in the output stream as a zip file.